# Architecture on a .net 3.5 webforms website using Json, html, jquery, Knockout.js exclusively

Tags: asp.net, json, knockout.js, webforms, breeze

I'm starting a somewhat greenfield web application that needs to run within a .net 3.5 webforms website, but otherwise will be detached in terms of interactivity with the current site.  I am trying to design an architecture that would minimize or eliminate the use of webforms.  So far I've come up with using wcf web services in json (web api is unfortunately not an option due to the 3.5 restriction) and having Knockout.js exclusively on the client side.  Ideally I would not add aspx pages but straight html pages to build the UI front.

1) Is this possible/reasonable?

2) Would I be able to implement asp.net utility functionality like windows authentication and user roles access security using html pages with knockout.js instead of aspx pages?

Comment: 1) Yes, possible. Although you might want to look at using the new WebAPI instead of WCF. It's a more natural fit. 2) Your web services can use Windows authentication if properly configured. You don't need to go fully static web pages either.

Comment: You must have .net 4.0 and up installed on the IIS to use WebApi right?  We are running 3.5.

Comment: Yes it is possible.You can use web-methods for ajax call and can use it in html page.

Comment: @RMuesi - might be time to upgrade to 4.0 if you're considering such other large changes. WCF is overkill for your scenario. .net 3.5 was released Nov. 2007. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking to minimize the actual amount of work and prefer to keep things AS SIMPLE as possible I would recommend at least taking a look at using ServiceStack. It'll do most everything you'll want WebAPI to do but it runs on NET3.5 and it has different formats available to consume including SOAP (yeah, people still use that). The best part is you don't have to write any other code to get all the formats. It has the ability to also output HTML as a format just as easily as it would JSON, JSV, XML, SOAP, etc.

You'd be good to employ Knockout.js and perhaps BreezeJS (http://www.breezejs.com) too for change tracking. 
http://www.servicestack.net/

Comment: +1 for ServiceStack.  Wish you had answered this 15 hours ago!  Spent most of the day working through confusing wcf code only to stumble upon SS and feel totally saved.  Appears to be the perfect solution to my problem thus far.  I also decided to try out Breeze, but swap out KO for Angular.  We'll see how it goes.  Thx.

Comment: Nice, I haven't tried any Angularjs stuff yet. Sorry I didn't answer 15 hours ago, I was in bed! :-)